# Who is responsible for adding new JavaScript features?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Which organization is appointed for implementing new JS features? For example, adding a new reverse string capability, or anything else that would be introduced in ESNext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ES" stands for "ECMA Script". ECMA International is the organization that standardizes Ecma Script. To be more precise, there is [Technical Committee 39](https://www.ecma-international.org/technical-committees/tc39/) or TC39 responsible for this particular standard.  Members  of the committee are people from different organizations like  Microsoft and PayPal. Also there is invited experts, who are not on committee, but also help to develop the language.

They have a [process](https://tc39.es/process-document/) of proposing and introducing features. This process is public and uses [GitHub](https://github.com/tc39) where you can read about what was proposed and propose your own features.

As for implementation - it is responsibility of browser vendors. Most browsers now open sources (at least partially), so you can also contribute.